# Hide React components on server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

To the point, I'm working a React app that has "levels" where users have to completely some tasks before then can move on to the next one. And for obvious reasons I can't use client-side js to verify and advance the user to the next level.

I believe that a server should handle this, but I'm stuck on how to go implementing this. I've tried Googling for this but I'm not sure if I can accurately put this into keywords. Some of my current thoughts:

- Render React components of each levels to static html then serve this page when the correct request is made to the server (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html). As my whole app is running client-side now, I'm worried that this will complex things a lot more.
- Keep all the components client-side but only return the link (route) to the page if a request is made to the server. This way someone extremely motivated can still see all the pages without completing the tasks.

I believe there should be an obvious answer to this question but since I'm relatively new to React, I'm not sure what it is.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

React is a client-side framework.  Meaning it is run and rendered in the browser. 
When you talk about "the server" you are needing to implement a backend framework (i.e. RoR or Express), this is something you will have to learn independently.  There are many tutorials online that are free.